# Can this JavasScript regular expression \.(md|njk|md\.njk)$ be simplified further?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match these strings:

```
foo.md     -> capturing group should be: (.md)
foo.njk    -> capturing group should be: (.njk)
foo.md.njk -> capturing group should be: (.md.njk)
```

... capturing **all after the first dot (EDIT: but still, extension should be md or njk or md.njk)**.

This is what I've done: `\.(md|njk|md\.njk)$` ([test](https://regex101.com/r/SSYUmF/3)) in the first place, and it works.

I've tried to simplify it, so I ended up with another one: `\.(md|(md\.)?njk)$` ([test](https://regex101.com/r/SSYUmF/2)) that it's a bit better, but still repeats the words "md".

Can't be simplified further or not?

Comment: @Fraction still taking the extension into account (that is md|njk|md.njk)

Comment: Maybe you wanna try this `\.\b(md)?\.?(njk)?$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/hEO6Yg/1. Note that this matches `mdnjk` (no dot between).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to capture **anything** that is after the first dot I think you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/vezMI8/3)

`/\.(.+)$/gi`

[image]

EDIT : As Fraction mentioned in comment, putting `$` at the end is not a bad idea

Comment: ops... yes but no, I still want to match the extension.

Comment: What is is you exactly want to match, ? Other wise you can put another group capture to capture the latest dot

Comment: Please see my updated question. Extension md|md.njk|njk is mandatory.

Comment: Check @Skolak 's answer I believe this is what you need. Can't be shorter if you need to check all those extensions

Comment: Sorry but it's not what I asked. For example, foo.exe should not match.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
/\.((md)?(\.)?(njk)?)$/
```